# Angular Material Component: MatDialog backdrop only on certain area

Tags: angular, angular-material

When i open an Angular Material Dialog (MatDialog) the backdrop cover all the application, eg.:

[image]

I want the backdrop only on certain area, eg.:

[image]

there is a a way to set the backdrop to cover only a specific component?

i have found a workin example for Angular 4, but doesn't work on Angular 8
https://reppners.github.io/ngx-cdk-dynamic-overlay-container/

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but when you open a dialog, you can pass a MatDialogConfig and it has the backdropClass property ```this.matDialog.open(dialogComponent, dialogConfig)```

Comment: Even if you succeed in displaying side components, if the use clicks roughly anywhere by default mat dialog will close and you will get the same screen again.